# Associate JDBC Datasource Name Using @JdbcRepository annotation

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

In the [docs](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#jdbc), it states,

> The @JdbcRepository annotation accepts an optional string value which represents the name of the connection or datasource in a multiple datasource scenario. By default Micronaut Data will look for the default datasource.

However, I don't see any such value parameter within this annotation - only the dialect.
Is this an error or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete snippet, using dialect & datasource:

```
@Repository(value = "inventoryDataSource")
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.ORACLE)
public interface PhoneRepository extends CrudRepository<Phone, Integer> {
    Optional<Phone> findByAssetId(@NotNull Integer assetId);
}
```

A patch/pull request has been submitted with correction to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an error or am I missing something?

I think it is the former.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues we can take care of that.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Adding `@Repository('my-datasource-name')` should do.

Comment: @SaschaFrinken I think part of the issue is that it looks like our docs are inconsistent with the current implementation.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown : Added a pull request with correction https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/pull/478

Comment: Many thanks for the quick turn around @JeffScottBrown!